# Algorithim and flowchart for intersection and union of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm given $A= \{3,4,2,5\}$ and $B = \{a,3,b,5\}$. The intersection is $\{3,5\}$ elements in common.
The union is $\{2,3,4,5,a,b\}$.

How can I represent this intersection and union algorithmically and on a flowchart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows,

```
x in A
```

can be taken as shorthand for

```
x == 2 or x == 3 or x == 4 or x == 5
```

and similarly for `B`.

**As flowcharts**

*Union*

```
                   < x in A? >
               No /          \ Yes
                  |         True
             < x in B? >
         No /          \ Yes
          False       True
```

*Intersection*

```
                   < x in A? >
               No /          \ Yes
               False         < x in B? > 
                         No /          \ Yes
                          False       True
```

**Algorithmically**

*Union*

Set `result` to `True` or `False` according to whether `x` is or is not in the union of `A` and `B`.

```
if x in A:
    result = True
else:
    if x in B:
        result = True
    else:
        result = False
```

*Intersection*

Set `result` to `True` or `False` according to whether `x` is or is not in the intersection of `A` and `B`.

```
if x in A:
    if x in B:
        result = True
    else:
        result = False
else:
    result = False
```

Comment: Thanks for a hint here. But i think , as for intersection, we have to index every element in A and compare it to B then , if it is existed in both sets, shift it to a new set that is A intersection B ?? Is It right doing that way?

Comment: That sounds clumsy, I have to say — anyway, it's inefficient. The question doesn't ask, "given sets $A,B$, return a set $C$ that is their intersection" (or their union). It just asks you how to decide membership in the intersection (or union). There's no need to explicitly create a new set representing $A\cap B$ or $A\cup B$.

Comment: Again thanks very much for giving this food for thought...

Comment: can i use the flowchart the way you posted BrianO or i have to use rectangles representing this membership?

Comment: You should use whatever the conventions are for drawing flowcharts that your book or course defines. Different shapes are dedicated to different purposes -- often, angled sides for decision points (like `x in B?`), rectangles for actions, and so on. I didn't and don't want to get into the finer points of diagramming them, as that strays into territory that's not mathematical (and is really of little interest in itself).

Answer (score 0):

Basic procedure (for intersection) looks like this in math symbols:

$$ x \in (A \cap B) \Leftrightarrow (x \in A) \And (x \in B) $$

For union it's
$$ x \in (A \cup B) \Leftrightarrow (x \in A) \| (x \in B) $$